# Alias for Start/Stop Postgres as root

Tags: macos, zsh

I have installed `Postgres` on my M1 mac using a `dmg` file which I downloaded from their website. The homebrew installation was causing some issues, that's why I installed it this way.

Previously with `homebrew` I could start/stop `postgres` using `brew services start/stop postgres`. Currently I have to do this
`sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/14/data start/stop` to start/stop the server. I tried to make things a bit easier by adding an alias to `.zshrc` file, but as I learned I can't just add a command to shell with `sudo` like that.

My question is there any way to add an alias to simplify the start/stop of postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function instead of an alias:

```
start_postgres() {sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/14/data start}
```